# Why is my ASCII art all wonky?

Tags: candy-box-2

Nothing looks right in the ASCII art.  It looks wrong and nothing is proportional, how do I fix this? I have tried fiddling with my font size, but nothing still looks right!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you link a screenshot? It's hard to suggest a solution when we can't see *how* the art looks wrong.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your zoom? Ctrl 0

Comment: didnt work :/ sad

Comment: Are you, perhaps, enforcing fonts in your browser settings?

Comment: ii think so  O.O i am, how do i undo it in chrome? i can't seem to find how

Comment: Just google "<your browser name> set fonts". In case of Chrome it's explained [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en). Just make sure your monospaced font is actually monospaced.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: is it the black that is bad? if so just turn off the anti colors thing in the options.

Comment: Side question: What if, for example, your characters that are tildes (tildae?) show up as a weird A=c or whatever character? That happens on Firefox at home but not at work, and IE at home is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you have a monospaced font set.  If you're using a Mac, you should have one called "Monaco". Instructions for chrome for setting fonts: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I have a mac.  Found that on Firefox, my ASCII art was all wonky and the buttons didn't show up.  Game didn't even show up on Safari.  Everything seemed to be working ok in Chrome.  Would suggest trying out the game on different browsers to see if that ends up working for you.